# Implement profile popup on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to implement a profile popup like Books app on iOS. Do you know any package or something to make this? Thank a lot.

GIF below shows the behavior that I want to implement:
https://gph.is/g/EvAxvVw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use showModalBottomSheet, included in the flutter material package. Here's the reference for it: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

Comment: Ok tks. I will try this one

Comment: Yup. It fits my idea. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[beautiful popup](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beautiful_popup) package may be help to you in implement beautiful profile popup in app.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this one